# loop through json object in php

Tags: php, json

I've json object and I want to make addition of 'quantity' field in it. My code is [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1022634/Loop-through-json-object-in-php)

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
   $posts = json_decode($row['value'],true);
   array_push($response,$posts);
  }
   //print_r($response);
   foreach($response as $value){
         //$plus +=1;
         $plus = $plus+$value['quantity'];
   }
```

`print_r($response)` then gives:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [srno] => 1
                    [name] => Gaspari Aminolast
                    [quantity] => 2
                    [price] => 2920.0000
                    [total_bill] => 5840
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [srno] => 2
                    [name] => Gaspari Amino Max
                    [quantity] => 2
                    [price] => 2640.0000
                    [total_bill] => 5280
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [srno] => 3
                    [name] => Myofusion 10Lbs
                    [quantity] => 2
                    [price] => 8400.0000
                    [total_bill] => 16800
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [srno] => 1
                    [name] => Gaspari Aminolast
                    [quantity] => 2
                    [price] => 2920.0000
                    [total_bill] => 5840
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [srno] => 2
                    [name] => Gaspari Amino Max
                    [quantity] => 2
                    [price] => 2640.0000
                    [total_bill] => 5280
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [srno] => 3
                    [name] => Myofusion 10Lbs
                    [quantity] => 2
                    [price] => 8400.0000
                    [total_bill] => 16800
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [srno] => 1
                    [name] => Gaspari Aminolast
                    [quantity] => 2
                    [price] => 2920.0000
                    [total_bill] => 5840
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [srno] => 2
                    [name] => Gaspari Amino Max
                    [quantity] => 2
                    [price] => 2640.0000
                    [total_bill] => 5280
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [srno] => 1
                    [name] => Gaspari Aminolast
                    [quantity] => 2
                    [price] => 2920.0000
                    [total_bill] => 5840
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [srno] => 2
                    [name] => Gaspari Amino Max
                    [quantity] => 2
                    [price] => 2640.0000
                    [total_bill] => 5280
                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [srno] => 1
                    [name] => Gaspari Amino Max
                    [quantity] => 2
                    [price] => 2640.0000
                    [total_bill] => 5280
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [srno] => 2
                    [name] => Gaspari Aminolast
                    [quantity] => 2
                    [price] => 2920.0000
                    [total_bill] => 5840
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: dou you want to increment all [quantity] by a value

Comment: I want to get sum of all  [quantity] whatever returned by query

Comment: @Vg quantity of what? You need to be really explicit about what quantity should equal, and what it is a sum of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
plus = 0;
foreach($response as $value){
     //$plus +=1;
   foreach($value as $val)
   {
     $plus = $plus+$val['quantity'];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is your array is double-nested. You have a 2D array of key=>value pairs

```
foreach($response as $array){

    foreach($array as $value){
        $plus = $plus+$value['quantity'];
    }

}
```